# how to use variable names that are stored in SQL tables in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays, preg-replace, str-replace

I have something like this that is coming from my sql query. I am storing the variable names hoping that I can just pass the variable values in php but it is not recognizing the values.

```
[{"dataField":"711","caption":"Product Gas Type","max_length":2,"min_length":0,"validationRules":[{"type":"pattern","pattern":"^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{'.$minVal.','.$maxVal.'}$","message":"This field only accepts letters and numbers. The lentgh has to be between '. $minVal .' and '. $maxVal .'"}]},{"dataField":"712","caption":"1St Charge Charging Point","max_length":2,"min_length":0,"validationRules":[{"type":"pattern","pattern":"^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{'.$minVal.','.$maxVal.'}$","message":"This field only accepts letters and numbers. The lentgh has to be between '. $minVal .' and '. $maxVal .'"}]}]
```

I am trying to say:

```
   $minVal=1; 
   $maxVal=4;
```

but my $result variable never recognizes the variable(min and max vals) values. How can I do something like this? my ideal end result is something like this:

```
   [{"dataField":"711","caption":"Product Gas Type","max_length":2,"min_length":0,"validationRules":[{"type":"pattern","pattern":"^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{1,4}$","message":"This field only accepts letters and numbers. The lentgh has to be between 1 and 4"}]},{"dataField":"712","caption":"1St Charge Charging Point","max_length":2,"min_length":0,"validationRules":[{"type":"pattern","pattern":"^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{1,4}$","message":"This field only accepts letters and numbers. The lentgh has to be between 1 and 4"}]}]
```

I have tried doing the following:

```
 print_r(str_replace('$minVal', $minVal,$result[$i]->validationRules[0]->pattern));
```

this prints the correct thing but it doesn't alter my original variable ($result) and also when I try to add the same for $maxVal it  replaces $minVal with the word $maxVal

I also tried using pre_replace but that won't even print anything

I think the problem may be that this variable names are inside the $result and inside result there is validationRules array and so maybe that is why string replace is not able to access them and change the entire original array

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You would have to use `eval()`, but this becomes very problematic. I suggest you look into using a template library.

Comment: The `str_replace()` method should work. But you shouldn't have the `.` concatenation operator in the SQL data. The SQL data is not executed as PHP code, so you shouldn't have operators, quotes, etc.

Comment: You can use sprintf ([example](https://eval.in/private/36948631fa0114)), but when there's multiple repeated variables you'll start to have to implement or use a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

The raw output is just plain text and will not recognize variables as substrings. You can try something ugly like this (and it will work):

```
$raw_output = '{"dataField":"711","caption":"Product Gas Type","max_length":2,"min_length":0,"validationRules":[{"type":"pattern","pattern":"^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{'.$minVal.','.$maxVal.'}$","message":"This field only accepts letters and numbers. The lentgh has to be between '. $minVal .' and '. $maxVal .'"}]},{"dataField":"712","caption":"1St Charge Charging Point","max_length":2,"min_length":0,"validationRules":[{"type":"pattern","pattern":"^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{'.$minVal.','.$maxVal.'}$","message":"This field only accepts letters and numbers. The lentgh has to be between '. $minVal .' and '. $maxVal .'"}]}';
```

Then explode on $minVal string:

```
$explode = explode("' . $minVal . '", $raw_output);
$count = count($explode);
$count_minus_one = $count - 1;
$processed_output = '';
for($i = 0; $i < $count_minus_one; $i++) {
    $processed_output .= $explode[$i] . $minVal;
}
$processed_output .= $explode[$count_minus_one];
```

Then repeat for $maxVal.